# How to tidy up a massive spaghetti project

Tags: java, project-management

I previously asked this on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355249/how-to-tidy-up-a-massive-spaghetti-project), but was advised it was a better fit for Programmers.

I have recently begun working on a codebase (as a Java developer) with the following characteristics:

- Roughly 800,000 lines of source (including whitespace and comments). Primarily Java, but also XML, PHP, Shell scripts, JSP, JS, HTML, CSS
- Frameworks: Mainly Stripes, a bit of Struts, and some quite old customised Hibernate (and I expect lots of other bits and bobs).

  No particular methodology for stories, sprints etc.

  No tests

  No build process

  No dependency management (everything is just setup in IDEA)

  Some very old code dating back as far as 2002

  No coding standards

  Masses of code redundancy, though given the lack of tests this is difficult to track down

  Multiple modules and inter-dependencies

  A massive 10,000 line XML file containing named Hibernate queries

  'Dump-all' classes at the top of the inheritance tree containing references to multiple services that may only be used in a handful of child-classes (As an example, one class is extended by 573 classes. A particular service contained in it is used by only 3 children)

  Demotivated developers

I know this a really open-ended question: Where would you start in trying to tidy up this system?

Comment: @WorldEngineer this question is "how should I tidy up this system?" while the other one was "what would be a good way to teach people not to do it again?". I think even if the title resembles each other they are not duplicates

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: Personally I'm happy with the duplicate question, but if others feels modifying my question could make it more useful, please do :)